# How to show timestamps in short format in Jenkins Blue Ocean?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

Using [Timestamper plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/) 1.11.2 with globally enabled timestamps, using the default format, I get the following console output:

```
00:00:41.097  Some Message
```

In Blue Ocean the output shows like:

```
[2020-04-01T00:00:41.097Z] Some Message
```

How can I make it so that Blue Ocean uses the short timestamp format? The long format is somewhat unreadable and clutters the details view of the steps.

I've looked at the [Pipeline Options](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options) too, but there is only the `timestamps` option which doesn't have a parameter to specify the format.

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059004/what-can-cause-difference-in-timestamps-between-console-view-and-blueocean-view) isn't a dupe, because it asks for differences in time zone only.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

⚠️ Unfortunately this workaround doesn't work in the context of `node`, see [JENKINS-59575](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59575). Looks like I have to finally get my hands dirty with plugin development, to do stuff like that in a supported way.

Anyway, I won't delete this answer, as the code may still be useful in other scenarios.

---

**Original answer:**

As a workaround, I have created a custom [`ConsoleLogFilter`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/console/ConsoleLogFilter.html). It can be applied as a pipeline option, a stage option or at the steps level. If you have the timestamp plugin installed, you should disable the global timestamp option to prevent duplicate timestamps.

Typically you would define the low-level code in a shared library. Here is a sample that can be copy-pasted right into the pipeline script editor (you might have to disable Groovy sandbox):

```groovy
import hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream
import hudson.console.ConsoleLogFilter
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

pipeline{
    agent any
    /*
    options{
        // Enable timestamps for the whole pipeline, using default format
        //withContext( myTimestamps() )

        // Enable timestamps for the whole pipeline, using custom format
        //withContext( myTimestamps( dateFormat: 'HH:mm:ss', prefix: '', suffix: ' - ' ) )
    }
    */

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            options {
                // Enable timestamps for this stage only
                withContext( myTimestamps() )
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'

                // Enable timestamps for some steps only
                withMyTimestamps( dateFormat: 'HH:mm:ss') {
                    echo 'Hello World'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//----- Code below should be moved into a shared library -----

// For use as option at pipeline or stage level, e. g.: withContext( myTimestamps() )    
def myTimestamps( Map args = [:] ) {
    return new MyTimestampedLogFilter( args )
}

// For use as block wrapper at steps level 
void withMyTimestamps( Map args = [:], Closure block ) {
    withContext( new MyTimestampedLogFilter( args ), block )
}

class MyTimestampedLogFilter extends ConsoleLogFilter {
    String dateFormat
    String prefix
    String suffix

    MyTimestampedLogFilter( Map args = [:] ) {
        this.dateFormat = args.dateFormat ?: 'YY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
        this.prefix     = args.prefix ?: '['
        this.suffix     = args.suffix ?: '] '
    }

    @NonCPS
    OutputStream decorateLogger( AbstractBuild build, OutputStream logger )
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return new MyTimestampedOutputStream( logger, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, this.dateFormat, this.prefix, this.suffix )
    }
}

class MyTimestampedOutputStream extends LineTransformationOutputStream {
    OutputStream logger
    Charset charset
    String dateFormat
    String prefix
    String suffix

    MyTimestampedOutputStream( OutputStream logger, Charset charset, String dateFormat, String prefix, String suffix ) {
        this.logger = logger
        this.charset = charset
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat
        this.prefix = prefix
        this.suffix = suffix
    }

    @NonCPS
    void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        logger.close();
    }

    @NonCPS
    void eol( byte[] bytes, int len ) throws IOException {
        def lineIn = charset.decode( java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap( bytes, 0, len ) ).toString()
        def dateFormatted = new Date().format( this.dateFormat )
        def lineOut = "${this.prefix}${dateFormatted}${this.suffix}${lineIn}\n" 
        logger.write( lineOut.getBytes( charset ) )
    }
}
```

Example output for stage "B":

[image: Blue Ocean Output]

**Credits:**

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284198/7571258).